# Spring aspects across multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, aop

Trying to wrap service class with two aspects to get this call chain:

`javanica..HystrixCommandAspect` -> `MyCustomAroundAspect` -> `MyService`

met two problems:

1. `HystrixCommandAspect` does not call `joinPoint.proceed()`. Instead it calls method directly on target class, which effectively skips any other proxies created after javanica's aspect
2. Hystrix aspect makes subsequent calls running in deferent thread. It leads to message:

   "No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress, and that the `ExposeInvocationInterceptor` is upfront in the interceptor..."

which is reasonable because this interceptor keeps its stuff in thread local.

Questions:
1. Why is Spring APO implemented this way? Is it conceptually wrong to run different aspects in different threads? Are there workarounds except changing the aspects' order?

2. Why does `HystrixCommandAspect` call target class directly, but not through `joinPoint.proceed()`? Doesn't it break the contract (if one even exists)?

regards

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am not a Spring or Hystrix user, just an AOP guy.*

> Why does `HystrixCommandAspect` call target class directly, but not through `joinPoint.proceed()`? Doesn't it break the contract (if one even exists)?

Actually, you have to ask the Hystrix maintainer. It is a good question, actually. the assumption that Hystrix aspects are the only ones in this universe is certainly a bold one because there actually is an AspectJ or Spring AOP contract for `@Around` advices:

- Either the aspect calls the original method. If it does so, it ought to use `proceed()`. If it proceeds with the original method arguments or with a modified set, is up to the aspect. Also if it proceeds before, after or in between doing other things.
- Or the aspect returns a result (for non-void methods) calculated without proceeding to the original method.
- Or the aspect throws an exception, not returning any result.

Having said that, I think it is a design flaw in Hystrix not to pass on the `ProceedingJoinPoint` and eventually call `proceed()` on it in case the original method is to be called eventually. If I was a Hystrix user, I would open a bug ticket for that.

Besides, it is in principle no problem to call `proceed()` asynchronously from another thread in which you inject the joinpoint instance upon creation. Then you can put that thread (or a runnable) into a queue and execute it whenever convenient. Technically you can even call `proceed()` on the same joinpoint instance multiple times, but if the target method is no pure function without side effects you might want to be careful with that and usually won't do it unless your aspect implements some kind of retry scheme (with or without exponential back-off). So Hystrix could to that too. If they do not then they must be doing something ugly instead, such as use reflection to call the original method. I did not check.